# Customize Chrome to show the count of tab groups instead of tabs

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser-tabs

When Google Chrome rolled out the tab group feature on Android, it used to show the number of tab groups.
Ever since a recent update, they made it so that Chrome shows the total number of tabs instead. Is there a way to revert this?

[image]